# Reading Griffiths Harris: Quick question

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Why is a meromorphic section without zeros and poles on a compact Riemann surface necessarily a constant? Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by section ? Do you mean map to the Riemann sphere ?

Comment: Just  check it locally. From the complex plane, you can see this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a global holomorphic section $s$ of a line bundle $L$ on a compact, connected Riemann surface $M$. $s$, being nowhere zero, gives a holomorphic trivialization of the line bundle; i.e., $L \cong M\times \Bbb C$. Holomorphic sections of the trivial bundle are holomorphic functions, and the only holomorphic functions on such an $M$ are constant functions (for example, non-constant holomorphic functions are open maps).

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Sorry for being slow. May I ask why there cannot be a non-trivial open map between a surface and the Riemann Sphere minus two points?

Comment: @Bombyx mori: Compactness. The modulus of the holomorphic function must have a maximum.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Of course you meant " a global holomorphic section without zeroes".

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks!

Comment: @orangeskid, yes, thanks. The nowhere-zero disappeared when I was editing. I'll correct.